# Getting a Mongodb ArrayOfObjects value from POJO class with Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am facing an issue(getting Null Value) while  getting the Mongodb  value from the ArrayOfObjects and My POJO class is like below :I have created separate POJOS for Each Object .Can anyone help me how to fetch the value of Email Systems.Bob.System .
My Document :

```
"Email Systems" : [
        {
            "Bob" : {
                "System" : "Bob", 
                "result" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Wild" : {
                "System" : "Wild", 
                "result" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "CRaft" : {
                "System" : "Craft", 
                "result" : false
            }
        }
    ]
```

My POJO Class :

```
public class Bob{
    @JsonProperty("System") 
    public String system;
    public String result;
}

public class Wild{
    @JsonProperty("System") 
    public String system;
    public String result;
}

public class CRaft{
    @JsonProperty("System") 
    public String system;
    public String result;
}

public class EmailSystem{
    @JsonProperty("Bob") 
    public Bob bob;
    @JsonProperty("Wild") 
    public Wild wild;
    @JsonProperty("CRaft") 
    public CRaft cRaft;
}

public class Root{
    @JsonProperty("EmailSystems") 
    public List<EmailSystem> emailSystems;
}
```

Comment: Yes , JSON is valid

Comment: have you populated data before accessing it from POJO? your JSON should be enclosed with "{}".

Comment: {"Email Systems":[{"Bob":{"System":"Bob","result":true}},{"Wild":{"System":"Wild","result":true}},{"CRaft":{"System":"Craft","result":false}}]}  is correct json

Comment: Yes , I have just provided the sample , and taken from braces "{}" .

Comment: Thank you for your reply , Can you help me to get the value as value is retruning the null value

Comment: as i asked have you populated the data to your POJO?

Comment: if yes then can you post the code here?

Comment: I am not sure how to populate the data to POJO

Comment: come to chat window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225613/discussion-between-priyranjan-and-shiri).

Comment: I have joined the chat

Answer (score 0):

1st populate the JSON data to your POJO the try to retrieve from them then you will not get null value.

**Make sure you have GETTER/SETTER in all POJO.**
and also **"result"** field is **boolean**. but you can map with string  with("")

```
ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();

Root root = obj.readValue("jsonstring",Root.class);

they you can use getter to get the data.
```

**POM dependency:--**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

your JSON should be now:--- (as per POJO class)

```
  {
  "root": {
    "EmailSystems": [
      {
        "Bob": {
          "System": "Bob",
          "result": "true"
        }
      },
      {
        "Wild": {
          "System": "Wild",
          "result": "true"
        }
      },
      {
        "CRaft": {
          "System": "Craft",
          "result": "false"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried in that way but not able to provide the proper value Root root = obj.readValue("jsonstring",Root.class);                                                                                 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'jsonstring': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: are you really providing above JSON string?

Comment: if not then change result datatype to boolean